# Why does deleting an initializer not change behaviour?

Tags: java, ruby, sinatra, rack, stanford-nlp

In my Sinatra app, I am using the gems 'sinatra-initializers', 'sinatra/asset_pipeline', 'sinatra/assetpack' among others, and I have an initializer that loads a Natural Language Processing library:

```
#00_initializer.rb
    StanfordCoreNLP.jar_path = '/path/to/stanford-core-folder/'
    StanfordCoreNLP.model_path = '/path/to/stanford-core-folder/'
    NLPPipeline = StanfordCoreNLP.load(:tokenize, :ssplit, :pos, :lemma, :parse)

#nlp.rb
    def get_tokens(word)
        text = StanfordCoreNLP::Annotation.new(word)
        NLPPipeline.annotate(text)
        text.get(:tokens).each {|token| p token.get(:value).to_s} 
    end
```

When I start the server everything loads fine:

```
  >> $ rackup
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Loading default properties from tagger /Users/JW/Dropbox/Dev/Websites/FrontEnd/_JS plugins/stanford-core-nlp-minimal/taggers/english-left3words-distsim.tagger
Reading POS tagger model from /Users/JW/Dropbox/Dev/Websites/FrontEnd/_JS plugins/stanford-core-nlp-minimal/taggers/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.5 sec].
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file /Users/JW/Dropbox/Dev/Websites/FrontEnd/_JS plugins/stanford-core-nlp-minimal/grammar/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [1.5 sec].
Notice: for 10x faster LSI support, please install http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/
[2015-08-02 19:30:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-08-02 19:30:57] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
[2015-08-02 19:30:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=26229 port=9292
```

But as soon as I call the function, I get a

```
RuntimeError at /
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Everything loaded fine until yesterday, and as far as I know I changed nothing. Trying to dig around to see what was wrong, I commented out everything from the initializer. But still, the initializer loads exactly the same as before:

```
>> $ rackup
    Adding annotator tokenize
    Adding annotator ssplit
    Adding annotator pos
    Loading default properties from tagger /Users/JW/Dropbox/Dev/Websites/FrontEnd/_JS plugins/stanford-core-nlp-minimal/taggers/english-left3words-distsim.tagger
    ...[etc]
    [2015-08-02 19:30:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    [2015-08-02 19:30:57] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
    [2015-08-02 19:30:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=26229 port=9292
```

So... to my question: what's the deal with the phantom initializer? And, what could be the cause of my suddenly misbehaving Java library?

Comment: Are those "Adding annotator tokenize…" messages from the initializer or from the libraries being initialized?

Comment: From the third line in the initializer {NLPPipeline = StanfordCoreNLP.load(:tokenize, :ssplit, :pos, :lemma, :parse)}

Comment: The output must happen somewhere else then, as [`load`](https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp/blob/master/lib/stanford-core-nlp.rb#L140) doesn't output to the console itself. Are you using Bundler and what's in the config.ru?

Comment: Yes: here is my config.ru:         ` require 'bundler'
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require './app'

Bundler.require(:default)

map "/" do
 run HelloWorldApp
end`

Comment: You could try sandboxing the gems with `bundle install --binstubs --path=vendor`. It's obviously caching something *somewhere*. Check for generated files and remove them, but that would still be strange as it shouldn't then stop working for no reason.